# Dynamic URL alongside URL rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to have a URL like the following:

> http://example.com/product/category/name?ref=title

Where there is a URL Rewrite AND (at least 1) `?attribute=value` at the end of the URL.

How do I get the value of that attribute with the '?' before it? I have tried just using the basic `$_GET['']` to get the value, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: add the `[QSA]` flag with your url rewrite rule. `QSA` means "query string append" and will append any existing arguments to the rewritten url in addition to any you set in the get string. What does your rewrite rule look like?

Comment: How are your url rewrites handled? Probably you just need to add QSA flag

Comment: What is the context? Are you trying to capture it with a pattern in the `.htaccess` or are you looking to get the path from php?

Comment: I am looking to get all of the information from the URL including all the mod_rewrites AND the ?attr=val values

Comment: an example of what I am trying to do is similar to the path of this thread... "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203693/dynamic-url-alongside-url-rewrite?noredirect=1" it has what appears to be 3 items in the htaccess link, **/questions/28203693/dynamic-url-alongside-url-rewrite** and then one ?attr=val value **?noredirect=1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ideas:

`RewriteRule /page /index.php?attr=val [QSA]`

You can also use `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in the rewrite rule.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to use `%{QUERY_STRING}`?

Comment: @hugo `RewriteRule /page /index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&attr=value`